# How to display image with self-defined transparency from matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, transparency

I would like to display image directly from a matrix (not colormap). For example, I have a `100x100x3` matrix A, at position (i,j), it has color [0.5,1.0,0.8]. Using `imshow(A)` can directly display the image.

However, the alpha value cannot be specified. If I would like each pixel to have an additional alpha channel, for example [0.5,1.0,0.8,0.2], the `imshow` method complains.

Is there a way to accomplish this target?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlphaData` property of the `Image` returned by `imshow`

```
img = A(:,:,1:3);
alpha = A(:,:, 4);
i = imshow(img);
i.AlphaData = alpha;
```